# Revert wiki page in Trac

Tags: wiki, trac

How do you revert to an earlier version of a wiki page in Trac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it sounds complicated, but here's one way:

- Click on "History" at the top-left of the page.
- Click on the version you want to revert to. This will display the page at that version.
- At the bottom of the page, under "Download in other formats", click "Plain Text". This will download the source text for the desired version.
- Edit the page, delete the whole content and paste the source that you downloaded.

Admittedly, this could be made quite a bit simpler. Feel free to file a ticket on [the Trac site](http://trac.edgewall.org/) to request this enhancement (a quick search didn't yield anything).

Of course, if the version you want to revert to is the previous one, you could also just delete the current version. You will need `WIKI_DELETE` permission for that.

Comment: For the record, this should be improved shortly, see http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/10099

Comment: You added the feature to Trac! That's above and beyond the call of duty in answering an SO question.

Comment: Well, this has bugged me more than a few times, and your question just gave me the little push that was necessary to do something about it :)

Comment: I agree, this is something that needed improving.  This is the first time I've seen a SO question turn into an implemented feature almost immediately.  I'd give this answer a +10 if I could.  Thank you for your hard work!